# How to Monitor files that are present in another server

Tags: linux, centos, monitor

Can anyone please let me know if there are any ways that we can monitor a directory in centOS (linux) which is present in different server and when a new file arrives in that directory I need to copy that file to my server.

Comment: There are tons of ways to do this; one way would be using `rsync`.

Comment: Can we use rsync in Centos? If so can you please explain me how to do it (like steps to do) as I'm new to this. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Yes, `rsync` is a standard `unix/linux` utility - mostly for keeping files in sync from one server to another (**[info](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)**). You need to explain in more detail what your goal is, things like: (1) how often the directory needs to be checked (2) how are the servers talking with each other (3) what size are the files ... etc.

Comment: My goal is to monitor a directory continuously which is present in Host A and copy the files from Host A whenever new file come into that directory to Host B (my server) . At present I'm testing this kind of environment. So, I'm not worrying about file size. Host A and Host B should be communicating via private IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to have rync command running periodically on [cron job](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/crontab-every-10-min/).  `rysnc` is famous for its delta-transfer algorithm,  which reduces the amount of data sent over the network by sending
only the differences between the source files and the existing  files  in
the  destination.

If you want to run transfer from remote server to local server like every 10 minutes you add a line like below in your crontab. It also does few other things:

1. Zip the files
2. Transfer over ssh
3. Logs output

Note: You will have to do [ssh key exchange](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html) to avoid the password prompt.

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/rsync -zrvh -e ssh root@<remoteIP>:<remoteDir> >/var/log/rsync_my.log  2>&1
```

Comment: But when I'm trying to use rsync between two servers, rsync -vvv /home/username/rsynctest/* centos@172.31.46.199:/home/centos  it gave below error: opening connection using: ssh -l centos 172.31.46.199 rsync --server -vvve.Lsf . /home/centos
The authenticity of host '172.31.46.199 (172.31.46.199)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is f6:59:b3:d8:7f:3d:f8:9f:b2:d8:cc:d6:d4:17:d5:bc.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '172.31.46.199' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

Comment: This can be due to multiple reason .. one I can think of is - check your ssh setting on server you are connecting to ... in /etc/ssh/sshd_config  ... (hoping that centos login is defined)...1. http://serverfault.com/questions/598058/ssh-permission-denied-publickey-gssapi-with-mic-password  2. https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=7687

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Option 2 worked for me. I'll work on Cron task and will post if I come across any issue. Again.. Thank you so much. This helped me a lot. I was struggling a lot to get this.

Comment: I'm new to Stack Overflow and not sure how to make it as answer :(

Comment: Can you please let me know if there is any tool that has java code to monitor directory and transfer newly arrived files in that directory to another server?